# Help Identifying Frost Free Faucet Manufacturer

Tags: faucet

Can anyone help me in identifying who the manufacturer of this frost free faucet is?

I am needing to repair the faucet but have read that every one is just a *little* different, making a simple repair kit from the hardware store very hit-or-miss.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's made by [Mueller Industries](https://web.archive.org/web/20190221033154/http://www.muellerindustries.com/products/plumbing)

[image]
<sub>(source: [muellerindustries.com](http://www.muellerindustries.com/images/common/header/logo.png))</sub>

Maybe an older [QuarterMaster brass Anti siphon frost free sillcock](https://www.doitbest.com/products/408320)?

Comment: Awesome. Certainly looks right. Now the hunt is on for parts! Thanks!

Comment: FYI Mueller / B&K has a guide for identifying their sillcocks that I found helpful: https://bkproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/BK-Products-Sillcock-Identification-9c.pdf

Page 7 also talks about a design flaw that causes a leak at the handle. Also see the question on page 10 "Why does plugging the pinhole fix the handle leak?" that says, "Replacing the stem will also fix this leak."